# existential force and universal force

Tags: syntax, semantics, formal-semantics

I was reading the paper below, and because of my lack of knowledge on the linguistic terms, I have been stuck half way through. If you would be kind enough to enlighten me, I would be very much obliged. My take is 'existential force' points to, as it says, the phenomenon where the referent is in existence whereas 'universal force' points to the force that a free choice item has.

Incidentally, if you would also paraphrase the 'when it gets bound by an **unselective operator**' into lay person's terms I would also appreciate it.

> [E]xamples like (10) indicate that weak definites have the force of
>   the complement indefinite not only when the indefinite has
>   ***existential force***, but also **when it gets bound by an unselective operator** and acquires ***universal force***:
>
> (10) If the student of a linguist owns a donkey, he beats it.
>
> A different solution comes to mind, namely, that the reason why weak
>   definites have the interpretation we are interested in is because
>   their interpretation gets 'anchored' to that of the NP that serves as
>   complement of of, so that if that NP gets bound by an operator, these
>   definites get bound by that operator as well.[[Weak Definites][1] by
>   Massimo Poesio]
>
> [1]:
>   https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwiqsJenzbPjAhUvyYsBHXRIDmwQFjABegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjournals.linguisticsociety.org%2Fproceedings%2Findex.php%2FSALT%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F2465%2F2213&usg=AOvVaw0WebL6SH8Hw7Ba-J5hSa0O

Answer (score 2):

This refers to the *existential quantifier*, "exists X", and *universal quantifier*, "for all x", respectively in first order logic, which quantifies formulas over the elements of a set, not to be confused with higher order logic, that quantifies formulas over classes of formulas. The donkey-beating sentences are the canonical example in this context in linguistics. Whether *force* has special meaning in this context I do not know.

In priniple, there exists an isomorphism between *existential* terms and *universal* terms. That means, there is an equivalence between "for all donkeys owned by x it is true that they get beat by x" is equivalent to "for all students who each own a donkey, it is true that they beat it".

Comment: Thanks, so in a nutshell, 'existential force' corresponds to ∃xP(x) whilst 'universal force' to ∀xP(x). Am I correct?

Comment: It does not seem to be a term of art, as far as I know, but I know very little. Did you **follow the primary reference** named in the intro (not Russel, the other one)? I have no idea what *force* could be derived from in the native language of the author, if that held any clue (I was just dealing with Latin *fortis*, hence the tangent). I suspect they might mean *regime, domain* (in my words, derived from *regieren* "command"; any verb may command a certain casus; Now I'd like to think certain constructions are prone for universal force, comparable to definiteness). I didn't read the article!

Comment: Reading through the article I'm now pretty sure the 'forces' are what makes sentences require 'existential reading' and 'universal reading.' And thanks for your help!